# Finding a Core Data entity's property values

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a Core Data entity with four boolean non-optional properties, defaulted to NO. A class gets the entity object when the class is initialized, so this is not a result of an NSFetchResquest, and one of these four properties will be set to YES.
The class needs to know which property is YES.

Of course, I can use nested IF/Else statements (or ternaries) to find out which property is YES, but I'm wondering if there is a better (meaning more cocoa-ish) way to look at the entity and say 'is there a boolean value YES in your properties?'.

also, i can remodel to have the booleans have no value as default, and only look for the boolean that has YES, but that seems the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are several different possibilities. Using four different boolean properties is a clean solution. You then have to use the if ... elsif  statements to find out what happened.

A more C way of doing that would be to define bitmasks which can be OR'ed together and stored as an NSUInteger. If this would semantically makes sense you could group them together in an enum, but that is the C way.

You could also define a custom subclass of  `NSManagedObject` and write some convenience methods to check these options. Depends a bit on what they are good for.

Comment: since the entity is already a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, i can write some methods to check, and then use those in the class that is needing to know. thanks for jogging my brain!

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection (e.g., `class_copyPropertyList` and `class_getProperty`) to check what properties the class has, and examine their values, but that's a pretty heavy-handed approach when you already know which four properties are relevant. I wouldn't suggest this approach, and I wouldn't call it more Cocoa-ish, just more abstracted.

If you're looking at specific combinations of states, I think GorillaPatch's suggestion is right: You would turn those four booleans into a single 4-bit integer and compare it against bit masks representing the various combinations you're interested in.